# hola me podrian dar una mano con ejercicio en haskell

Tags: haskell

Hola estoy trabado en el siguiente ejercicio de un curso principiantes de haskell:
Teniendo las siguientes funciones:

```js
maximoEntreTres uno dos tres = max uno (max dos tres)
minimoEntreTres uno dos tres = min uno (min dos tres)
dispersion uno dos tres =  maximoEntreTres uno dos tres - minimoEntreTres uno dos tres
```

el ejercicio me pide  crear las siguientes funciones, que lo conseguí:

```js
    diasParejos uno dos tres = dispersion uno dos tres < 30
    diasLocos uno dos tres =  dispersion uno dos tres > 100
```

mi problema esta en la función 
**diasNormales**, que el resultado de la "dispersion" de sus parametros no sea ni diasParejos ni diasLocos(osea que este dentro de un rando de 31 y 99)  lo he probado de varias formas pero sigo sin conseguirlo:
probé de a siguiente forma:

```js
diasNormales = dispersion uno dos tres > 30 && dispersion uno dos tres < 100
```

//pero claro que esta solución no es adecuada porque se requiere usar las funciones diasParejos y diasLocos
agradecere mucho la ayuda

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú mismo lo sugieres:

> **diasNormales**:  ni diasParejos ni diasLocos

```
diasNormales uno dos tres =  not (diasParejos uno dos tres)
                          && not (diasLocos uno dos tres)
```

Alternativamente:

```
diasNormales uno dos tres = not (diasParejos uno dos tres
                                 or diasLocos uno dos tres)
```

Comment: hola gracias, por suerte tenia la idea de la respuesta con la negación de las funciones lo que no hacia era ponerlas en parentesis. Gracias además por la alternativa